# Can’t get a proper first layer on my Ender 3 pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, adhesion

I’ve been trying to level my bed for close to a week now and I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. I thought buying new springs and a glass bed would fix the problem, but it didn’t really help. I either have to raise the bed so high that almost no filament comes out or so low that there’s no adhesion.

On the attached photo there’s my last attempt. What should I do to fix those tears which run along the edge of the entire print

[image: Bad first layer showing tears along the edge of the print]